# is it possible with javascript to change the value of name property of input text?

Tags: javascript

is it possible for me to change "myname" with javascript?

```
<input type="text" id="myid" name="myname">
```

what i try to accomplish is I want to create function to change value of name.

Comment: document.getElementById('myid').name = "myname2222";  OR 

  document.getElementById("myid").setAttribute("name", "changedname"); 

works?

Comment: Sure it's possible. What have you tried, what does not work?

Answer (score 1):

There is `name` property which sets or returns the value of attribute with the same name.

```js
document.getElementById('myid').name = 'something';
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myid" name="myname"/>
```

Read more at W3Schools:

- [Input Text name Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_name.asp),
- [HTML DOM Input Text Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_text.asp) (with list of other properties)

Answer (score 0):

yes , it is possible and simple .

```
document.getElementById("myid").name = "whateveryouwant"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
document.getElementById("myid").setAttribute("name", "changedname");
```